# 10k+ Customer companies for all products - what does this mean?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

What does this number really mean, and is there a better way to explain it here:

[image]

Link is here: https://stackoverflow.com/company

Comment: [SO Enterprise](https://stackoverflow.com/enterprise) and [Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams)?

Comment: No red-hand crircle? And are you really proof-reading their marketing-meh for free?

Comment: @AndrewT. - I dont know - what I do know is I find a ton of these mishaps on the UI - I don't think anyone rereads or at least tries to get feedback on these pages.

Comment: @rene - You know me I read everything!

Comment: I would put a cross on it and call it a day ...

Comment: @rene - or remove it entirely :-D

Comment: I would assume they meant "company customers ...". So customers that are companies, rather than individuals.

Comment: The numbers are all kinds of meaningless. "45.1+ Billion Times a developer got help" What developer got helped 45.1 billion times? Did Jon Skeet help that developer every single one of those times?

Comment: Why shouldn't we help preventing them embarrassing themselves in public? Isn't it in our best interest? ([Meta]: Yeah, it could be better. Suggest.)

Answer (score 6):

Blind interpretation:

> Across all of our products, we are supporting 10,000+ [distinct] companies.

Not convinced it's a number that...matters...to a layperson like myself, but that's not up for debate here and now...

Comment: Hopefully, they haven't inflated [the numbers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pPJf8KrvJXU&t=11m55s).

Answer (score 5):

Most of these numbers are meaningless to me.

What does it mean that 19+ million questions have been asked? Is that good or bad? I think it's pretty bad, it means that we are not doing good enough job in curating existing content that people feel the need to keep asking more and more questions.

45 Billion times a developer got help? How is this counted? How do we know someone got the help they were searching for? Is it upvotes, anonymous upvotes or something else?

14.3 seconds between questions. I would be happier to see the average time between answers. Plenty of questions are rubbish and they never get answered.

10000 customers probably means that SO premium products have been sold to over 10k customers. How is this counted or what does it actually represent in terms of company's success I do not know.

Comment: But more is better! Don't you want to do what the popular people do?!

Comment: @CodyGray Some choose to take the code less traveled.